# \def\@absorbperiod.{} in LateX3?

Tags: latex3

In TeX:

```
\def\@absorbperiod.{}
```

will strip the period from the token stream.

I can't figure out a way to replicate this behavior in LaTeX3 (nor can I figure out a way to use this as a TeX command inside an ExplPackage.

I think I should be using a \peek_, but I'm not able to get that to work consistently; I *think* I should be trying to use \peek_after:Nw   but I don't understand what 'function' I'm supposed to be using.

I am aware of the xpeek package, which I believe might accomplish this specific instance, but I also want to be able to pass control sequences as parameters later (e.g \x\y passing \y to \x at #1) so I think understanding what I'm doing here is more important than just getting something to work.

Comment: `\cs_new:Npn \__astn_period_absorb:w . { }` should do, if you know for sure it will be followed by a period.  Something like `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__astn_check_period:w { \peek_charcode_remove:NTF . { <there was a period here> } { <no period> } }` if you want to check